# VHDL Implementing exclusive or data as a function

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, modelsim

I'm trying to pack simple code into a function.
Here is the VHDL code:

```
process(CLK, RST)
    variable newdata : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)  := (others => '0');
    variable tempdata : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin

    if (RST = '1') then
       tempdata := (others => '0');
       newdata  := (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
        tempdata := DIN;    
        newdata  := newdata XOR tempdata;
    end if;
    DOUT <= newdata;
end process;
```

[Code simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHxPu.png)

[RTL model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gus5p.png)

Everything works fine as i wanted to.
But if a trying implement this code as a function it will fail

```
function f_MOD2ALG (foo : std_logic_vector) 
return std_logic_vector;
...
function f_MOD2ALG (foo : std_logic_vector) 
return std_logic_vector is
    variable tempdata : std_logic_vector(foo'range);
    variable newdata  : std_logic_vector(foo'range);
begin
    tempdata := foo;
    newdata := newdata xor tempdata;
    return newdata;
end function;
```

[Fail simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxfyB.png)

[Fail RTL model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OykkG.png)

No errors, no warnings.

On the RTL model look's like he is nulle'd data input, but i dont understand why.
Can someon explain to me why it's happen? And how to properly create a function that's implement my code?
Thank's!

Here is the calling of the function:

```
...
signal temp     : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

process(CLK, RST)
begin
    if (RST = '1') then
        temp <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
        temp <= f_MOD2ALG(DIN);
    end if;
end process;
DOUT <= temp;
...
```

Comment: you dont show the function being used in code.

Comment: Oops, sorrry!
I paste it in the top post

Comment: The variable `newdata` inside your function will always be `"UUUUUUUU"` because it never gets initialized and it does not preserve its value between two function calls. And XORing something with `U` will always give `U`.

Comment: In the process you have edge sensitive sequential logic (a register) for newdata that's reset to all '0's. In the function there is no initial state specified and the data type is transformed to binary and assumed to be '0's. However every call to the function dynamically elaborates the declaration of newdata, it's always all '0's, just like in the RTL.  The function does not implement storage.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.6 Dynamic elaboration, 16.8 Standard synthesis packages, 16.8.2.4.2 Interpretation of the forcing and weak values ('0', '1', 'L', 'H', FALSE, TRUE).

Comment: Yeah, i understand. 
But if i initialize a variable `newdata` to 0's the function returns the same data as the input.
For example [CRC Generation Tool](https://www.easics.com/webtools/crctool) this tool generate a function without initialized value of variables and it's work correct.
What i need to do to make this function work properly?

Comment: The idea was to address your first question *Can someon explain to me why it's happen?*. .It's not clear why you're insisting on a function. Instead of `temp <= f_MOD2ALG(DIN);` you could `temp <= DIN xor temp;` because `temp` is reset. You can move the right hand side expression to a function should you feel the need. It implies both operands as parameters noting the function is already present in std_logic_1164 ("xor") and you could use an alias requiring parameters instead of operands.

Comment: [Using an alias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMdZq.jpg) instead of a new function declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already written in my comment, the issue with your code is that the variable `newdata` inside your function will always be `"UUUUUUUU"` because it never gets initialized and it does not preserve its value between two function calls. And XORing something with U will always give U.

If you initialize `newdata` to all zeros, the output will corresond to the input because XORing `foo` with `0` will give `foo`.

I know Easics' CRC generator. In their function, they pass the previous CRC value as argument. You could do something similar:

```
function f_MOD2ALG (foo : std_logic_vector; last_bar: std_logic_vector) 
return std_logic_vector is
    variable new_bar  : std_logic_vector(foo'range);
begin
    new_bar := foo xor last_bar;
    return new_bar;
end function;
```

And calling it somehow like that:

```
signal bar : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
...
process(clk)
begin
   if rising_edge(clk) then
      bar <= f_MOD2ALG(foo, bar);
   end if;
end process;
```